# Query to Azure AAD Returns only 20 members while there are more than 100 members

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to query Azure AD by using $expand=members to the end of the URL(as below). It however returns me only 20 members which I suppose is the default max. number. What is the way to get the list of all the members of a group?

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/12345-6789-1234-35234?$expand=members

I am using spark to query this. I would have been ok if it generated an oData.nextLink, but in this case it does not. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Well I was able to figure out myself that there is /members URL that returns all the members with an oData NextLink if the members are more than 100 in number.

Note - It only returns records that are "Users"(Not like Service Principal)